# How to combine 2 rows with different values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
id  date1     score1     date2     score2
1   today     80         today     88
1   yesterday 90         yesterday 92
```

The problem is that i need to Combine 2 rows into one row while in each column will be selected the highlighted values, on date1 the newest date follows matching score 1, the exact opposite will be done to date2 and score 2.

Comment: What Server you are using SQL Server, MySQL...? and give the expected output.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want for date1 and score to have values `yesterday` and `90` and for date2 to have `today` and `88` or other way around? Correct me if im wrong

Comment: I want the final result to be: id=1 , date1=today, score1=80, date2=yesterday, score2=92

Comment: Are u storing date1 and date2 in date format or string `today`, or is this just an example

Comment: Add some more sample table data and also specify the expected result. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I store the dates as strings but, it will be highly appreciated to understand also if it was stored as date types

Comment: using SQL server

Comment: If you store date as strings u mean date as `2018-04-10` or `today`. It would be easier for most of us to answer your question if you give clear sample data how it is stored in your database and expected output

Comment: 2018-04-10 for today and 2018-04-09 for yesteday

Comment: Try this and check `select date1+ cast (score1 as varchar(100)) first string, date2+ cast (score2 as varchar(100)) second string  from Mytable`  i can only understand this  from your question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand clear,Is that your expect?

```
SELECT  t1.ID,t1.DATE1,t1.score1,t2.DATE2,t2.score2
FROM T t1 
INNER JOIN T t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND DATEADD(DAY,1,t2.DATE2) = t1.DATE1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/593f8/1)

OR

In your question you might be like this query.

```
SELECT  t1.ID,t1.DATE1,t1.score1,t2.DATE2,t2.score2
FROM T t1 
INNER JOIN T t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.date2 = 'today' and t2.date2 = 'yesterday'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.date1,t1.score1,t2.date2,t2.score2
from yourTable t1
cross join yourTable t2 
where t1.date1 like 'today' and t2.date2='yesterday'
```

This works if you store date1 and date2 as strings 'today' and 'yesterday'